# Unhide purchases doesn't work

Tags: itunes, windows

In iTunes 12.2.2.25 running on Windows 7, I see my hidden music purchases on the account page. But when I press 'unhide' button nothing happens. How can I unhide it? Can I back to old iTunes versions?

UPD. It's the iTunes bug. Call iTunesStore support to resolve the problem, it will take some minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the hidden purchase are on a compilation/various artists album, this is unfortunately a [known bug](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7122259?start=0&tstart=0).